# Change fanatic/enthusiast badge to count more than just a page visit?

Tags: feature-request, activity-badges

The fanatic badge is by far the easiest of the gold badges to get. In fact, it's so easy you could setup a script to visit the page once a day and get the badge with no effort at all.

Therefore, I propose a change to the fanatic/enthusiast badge. I propose that you had to have actually done something to obtain it on each day. A list of possible activity I think is:

- Asked a question
- Answered a question
- Edited/retagged a post
- Commented on a post
- Voted to close/delete or reopen/undelete a question
- Flagged a post

Note that voting is left out. I think this is such a passive activity that it should not be counted as something to make it an "active" day.

So the new way the fanatic/enthusiast badge would work is that you are awarded it if you visit the site for 100/30 consecutive days and on each day do at least one of the actions above.

Comment: If it's so easy, how come you don't have it on Meta yet? ;)

Comment: Actually, since Electorate only requires 20 days of "passive" action, it's even easier to get than the silver Enthusiast

Comment: @Jon I'm at 89 days, so I'm about to get it. I've only been on meta 138 days anyway

Comment: Wow, you've only been here bothering us for 138 days? Sure seems like a lot longer than that... :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you're right that these badges are fairly easy to get, I don't agree about making them more difficult *in this way*.

People may try to force themselves to take one of these actions every day, just to keep up their streak. That would lead to low-quality content and actions, which are obviously Not a Good Thing(tm).

Answer (score 1):

> In fact, it's so easy you could setup a script to visit the page once a day and get the badge with no effort at all.

IIRC, Jeff said that you had to do marginally more than that. I suppose it might be to visit 2 different pages, but I'm not sure. So it's just a tiny bit harder than one page visit per day.

Comment: I think browser extensions [like this one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/38544/stack-overflow-notifier-chrome-extension) also cause SOFU to count a visit, as it scrapes each of the sites you have set up.

Answer (score 1):

I'll freely admit that I had a similar thought earlier today when I discovered much to my surprise that apparently I've visited Stack Overflow consecutively *for 332 days*.  I only became active on SO around [August of last year](https://stackoverflow.com/users/40468?tab=reputationhistory#tab-top), so I don't know how this could possibly be true.

[Now that I've had the Fanatic badge forever,] I'd find this "consecutive day visit" metric much more valuable if it indicated days on which I actually posted an answer, since while I do answer something nearly every day, it's certainly not *every* day. I don't even see a reputation change on some days.

So here's an orthogonal thought: I'd like to see a graph (much like that in the 'reputation' tab of one's user profile) that showed the number of answers and comments per day. Is anyone up to whipping up something like this using the API, or via a data-explorer query?