# Request to modify requirements for Fanatic Badge

Tags: feature-request, badges, activity-badges

I feel that the Fanatic badge requirements is little bit strict. Someone doing an activity for 90 consecutive days may easily have one of those odd days where its beyond his capabilities to do some activity. It could range from things like falling extremely ill, going mountain climbing, etc.

A possible way could be to maintain a Stack system for counting consecutive days. If user fails to do activity on a certain day, his contiguous count will be reduced, otherwise it will be increased. Since this would be way easy to achieve if the upper limit is only 100 days, that figure could also be revised, say 500 days.

The definition of activity could also be revised. Mere, viewing questions should not be counted. User must at least leave one answer, comments etc.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get rid of the "consecutive days" requirement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79995/get-rid-of-the-consecutive-days-requirement)

Comment: and [Change fanatic/enthusiast badge to count more than just a page visit?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54665)

Comment: Looks like SE is in no mood to change the requirements for the badge :). Still it would be nice if they did :( :D

Comment: If you can't fulfil the requirements of the badge then you are clearly not a fanatic :)

Comment: This is nuts. You aren't *entitled* to earning a gold badge. If you simply can't get on the computer for 100 days in a row, you simply won't earn the badge. It's *meant* to signify extreme dedication, not meant to be earned by everyone. Buy a freaking mobile phone if you want to earn this badge so desperately.

Comment: Currently I am carrying my laptop and 3G modem with me all the time when I am going outdoors, in order to not break the chain for the Fanatic badge.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Fanatic, is in my opinion the easiest gold badge.  You only have to visit the site 100 consecutive days. You don't even have to answer or comment on anything.

Its also the only gold badge that can be aquired without help from other people. (Unless you have 1000 IP addresses you can use).

So removing the only constraint isn't that wise to do.

Comment: True its easiest to get. I was very close to getting it, but then came the day where I just possibly could not manage to sit on the PC.

Comment: @Gunner,  I have had that once. But there will be 100 other days in the future.

Comment: @Gunner - I got to about 93 consecutive, and then got stuck on my travels without a WiFi hotspot in range in the outer wilds of some English hill country.  I was annoyed - but I got the (SO) Fanatic badge in the end.  I haven't bothered on the other sites.

Comment: if your comment about the ip addresses is in reference to the "famous question" gold badge then the figure should be 10,000.

Comment: @Brian Reichle, I refer to the publicist badge. http://stackoverflow.com/badges/262/publicist.

Comment: @Gamecat: Oops, missed that.

Comment: @Gunner - no offense, but you are a programmer. Write a 10-line app to fire off an HTTP request to your profile URL and leave it up indefinitely. :)

Comment: @one.beat.consumer no offence, but it would work only under certain circumstances, for example reliable internet provider. The ones I've dealt with required the router to be manually restarted on (ir)regular basis. So it's still easier to train your cat to restart router and log to SO for you (and phone your provider, if necessary).

Comment: I really just have to say I love this badge and hate both times so far that I got in the 90s and then missed a page refresh ^^ right on one.beat.consumer btw great profile