# Making the case for user defined time zones

Tags: feature-request, timezone

Before I begin, I understand that the site runs in GMT, that this provides an unprecedented level of consistency, and that there are numerous existing questions requesting the introduction of time zones, which have all been declined. However, I would like to make my case.

I like that there is a badge for being online on 100 consecutive days. It means you have to be dedicated to the community to get it, and that's a good thing. However, I live in EST, and three times I have been technicalitied-out of my consecutive days online streak on SO. This weekend was something different, and I'm not sour about that, but my March days online tell the story here. If I happen to be away from my computer until after 8pm, then even though it is clearly the same day where I am, the fact that the site runs in a different time zone means that if I'm in a rush in the morning, there's a possibility that I might not get credit for being here that day *even though I was*.

I get that everything being in UTC makes for complete consistency, but I literally cannot think of a modern website that doesn't allow the user to identify their own time zone - especially when there are achievements tied to it. Could the possibility of adding user-defined time zones please be entered back into consideration?

Comment: Bonus points if you can game the system by regularly alternating your user timzeone configuration between something that's -11:00 and something that's +13:00 so that you only actually have to log in every *two* days to get the credit? :-)

Comment: @Celada It's easier to just setup an auto-refresher than to keep on changing your timezone.

Comment: GMT is not necessarily UTC

Comment: Been here, asked GMT/UTC questions, learnt the lesson. At least you now know how the system works and can act appropriately! :)

Comment: Move to Europe. Problem solved.

Comment: +1 for turning _technicality_ into a verb, but -1 for using _unprecedented_ and _literally_ gratuitously. Also, -1 for admitting you've made the same mistake so many times, Homer, but +1 for sympathy.

Comment: I simply use the 3G internet connection on my phone to ensure I at least visit a question: it is enough to ensure the "visited" status, and you can do it easily even if you are in a rush in the morning. But the true challenge remains to answer at least one question a day.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> and three times I have been technicalitied-out of my consecutive days online streak on SO

Bzzzt. You are clearly not fanatical enough. No badge for you. Just wait till it happens again and you were on 99 days....

On a serious note, what you are suggesting is kind of similar to [previous](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/89649/request-to-modify-requirements-for-fanatic-badge) [suggestions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/79995/get-rid-of-the-consecutive-days-requirement) which have all been rejected because *a gold badge shouldn't be easy to to get. Not ever*.

To quote a [previous answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/80018/146015) on this subject:

> Someone who uses technicalities to insist they should be considered a fanatic is not a fanatic.

Comment: "Bzzzt" - We need a better sound for failure on 99 days.

Comment: @nickhar: [How about this?](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=zdCUpiI1MSA)

Comment: There's a difference between something being hard, and something being *artificially* hard. Being on for 100 consecutive days is hard. Being on for 100 consecutive days in a time zone that isn't your own is artificially hard. Also, if the only reason for keeping it away is to make that badge harder... that's not a good reason.

Comment: @DiMono The UTC standard on SE doesn't *exist* to keep people from earning the Fanatic badge, it exists to standardize the day for the purposes of timestamps, etc.  It's hard to please everyone in a situation like this, and UTC is a fair compromise, IMO.

Comment: @DiMono I know how you feel, but do remember that most of the world is offset from UTC, so you are in the same boat as everyone else. Keep plugging away at it, just remember when midnight UTC falls in your timezone :)

Comment: @hammer - I clicked that with the sole intention of being rick-rolled and was sorely disappointed :P.